# IsReadOnlyProperty.OverrideMetadata breaks mouse double-click commands in WPF DataGrid subclass

Tags: wpf, datagrid, double-click

I have a subclass for DataGrid which supplies some additional functionality and modifies the default values for some of its properties.  One thing in particular is I wanted the grid to be read-only by default, so I set `IsReadOnly = true` in its constructor.

Recently, I ran into an issue whereby using the grid in a template caused it to be read-only regardless how `IsReadOnly` was set in the template.  Looking at the [dependency property precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence#dependency-property-precedence-list) page, I reached the conclusion that [overriding metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/how-to-override-metadata-for-a-dependency-property) for `IsReadOnlyProperty` was the correct way to change its default:

```
IsReadOnlyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NewDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));
```

While this resolved the issue with control templates, it appears to break mouse double-click command bindings:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{StaticResource DoubleClickCommand}"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Is there a better way to change `IsReadOnly`'s default value without either breaking mouse bindings and/or templates?

###### Clarification about the command:

`DoubleClickCommand` itself is a `RoutedUICommand` defined in resources like so:

```
<RoutedUICommand x:Key="DoubleClickCommand"/>
```

Out of habit, I typically place this in the parent `Window` or `UserControl`'s resource dictionary, but I can move it to the grid's resources as well without any change in behavior.

The command is then attached to the grid's command bindings:

```
<DataGrid.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource DoubleClickCommand}" Executed="DoubleClick_Executed" CanExecute="DoubleClick_CanExecute"/>
</DataGrid.CommandBindings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that your issue is related to overriding the default value of the `DataGrid.IsReadOnly` property. There is no logical relation between a read-only `DataGrid` and mouse input events.

Instead it looks like the mouse events are handled by the internal elements of the `DataGrid` like `DataGridCell` - independent of the control's read-only state. For example double clicking the background of the `DataGrid` will work as expected, whereas clicking on a cell (or the content of a cell) won't.

To fix it, I suggest to override the control's `Control.OnMouseDoubleClick` and/or `Control.OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick` methods.
This should be generally your first approach before registering event handlers. First override the virtual members of the customized or extended control. It will give you greater control and your code looks cleaner too.
This is because the overrides are always invoked even if the override is a virtual event invocator (for example `Control.OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick`) and the control decides to not raise the public associated event.

So, instead of registering a mouse gesture, override the inherited event invocators:

```cs
public class NewDataGrid : DataGrid
{
  static NewDataGrid() 
    => DataGrid.IsReadOnlyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));

  protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
  {
    base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);

    if (e.LeftButton is MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
      // TODO::Handle left double click mouse input
    }
  }

  protected override void OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(e);

    if (e.LeftButton is MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
      // TODO::Handle left double click preview mouse input
    }
  }
}
```

This is not related to the recommended fix, but a general recommendation in regards to your original implementation: the way you set the `MouseBinding.Command` using the `StaticResource` markup extension looks odd. The command should be a `RoutedCommand` that is usually defined as `static` and referenced in XAML using the `x:Static` extension:

```cs
public class NewDataGrid : DataGrid
{
  public static RoutedCommand DoubleClickCommand { get; } = new RoutedUICommand(
    "Raise the tunneling and bubbling MouseDoubleClick event", 
    "DoubleClickCommand", 
    typeof(NewDataGrid));

  public NewDataGrid() 
  {
    var doubleClickCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(DoubleClickCommand, ExecuteDoubleClickCommand, CanExecuteDoubleClickCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(doubleClickCommandBinding); 
  }

  private void CanExecuteDoubleClickCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = true;

  private void ExecuteDoubleClickCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) 
  {
    var eventArgs = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, Environment.TickCount, MouseButton.Left);
    OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(eventArgs);
    OnMouseDoubleClick(eventArgs); 
  }
}
```

```xml
<NewDataGrid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                  Command="{x:Static local:NewDataGrid.DoubleClickCommand}" />
</NewDataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Comment: I don't know if it affects your suggestion any, but I added some clarification about `DoubleClickCommand` to the question.  It is a `RoutedUICommand` defined in a resource dictionary and attached to the grid via command bindings.

I define most of my commands this way, and I haven't run into any problems until now.

Comment: I see what's going on: the `DataGrid`'s [OnIsReadOnlyChanged](https://source.dot.net/#PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs,d628404dde8cb95c) handler ultimately has logic to notify its cells which ultimately sets them read-only as well.  When I override the default value for the property via metadata, this never gets fired, so the underlying cells remain read-write and swallow double-clicks as a means to enter edit mode, but since the grid as a whole is read-only, it doesn't do this, either.  I hadn't considered that, so thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Ah I see. Makes sense that you were defining the RoutedCommand in XAML. Wasn't expecting that. The first time I see somebody does this. The only downside I see with this is that you have to merge the containing ResourceDictionary in order to make the command available whereas a static filed is globally visible i.e. in the complete visual tree without paying attention to ResourceDictionary scopes. I guess it's especially problematic when deploying a library. You want to make the command visible without forcing the library client to merge resources. However, I'm happy we could solve your issue.